# How to redirect iPhone traffic over MacBook to sniff packets

Tags: iphone, ip, port, forwarding

I was somewhat curious to inspect packet exchanging between my iPhone and apps/other stuff, so I manually set its gateway to my laptop. I enabled port forwarding on my MacBook, and turned on Wireshark.

I see a lot of outgoing packets from the iPhone, yet I couldn't see any incoming packets. It seems like it didn't pass through my laptop but directly went to the iPhone.

Do I need to configure anything to see incoming packets?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about how the iphone packets directed to your macbook are sent to the internet?  Does the source address of the packet get NATted as they go through?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plug your MacBook's Ethernet into your network (such as a LAN port on your home gateway), then enable Internet Sharing from Ethernet to Wi-Fi. Use a different network name (SSID) on this network than you do on your main wireless network. Then make your iPhone join this new network that your MacBook is now publishing. Then run WireShark and you'll see all the traffic between the iPhone and the Internet.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is possible that to block a port on iPhone, blocking that port it on mac (perhaps using pfctl) will do the job? Thanks.